# Equation of Variation y with x

Tags: total-variation

$y-x= 1/x - 1/y$ where x and y are not equal to 0 then y varies ? (Complete)
I am supposed to know if it is direct or inverse variation but I did not manage to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y - x = 1/x - 1/y$, then we can rearrange as follows:
\begin{align*}
 xy(y - x) &= xy(1 / x - 1 / y) \\
\implies xy(y - x) &= y - x \\
\implies (xy - 1)(y - x) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
So either $xy = 1$ (ie $x = 1/y$, which is inverse variation), or $y = x$, which is direct variation. Indeed you can check that both of these satisfy the equation. So the answer is both! If you plot this equation, you get something like this:

[image: Graph]